# CI # Error Undefined property and Call to a member function get_data() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know, what to do to make it work, can someone help me, please?

The error shows like this :

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Undefined property: Data_Mobil::$rental_model

Filename: admin/data_mobil.php

Line Number: 6
```

and

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function get_data() on null
```

Here is my code :

Controller :

```
    public function index()
    {
        $data['mobil'] = $this->rental_model->get_data('mobil')->result();
        
        $this->load->view('templates_admin/header');
        $this->load->view('templates_admin/sidebar');
        $this->load->view('templates_admin/footer');
        $this->load->view('admin/data_mobil',$data);
```

Models :

```
class rental_model extends CI_Model{
    public function get_data($table){
        return $this->db->get($table);
    }
}
```

View :

```
               <?php
                $no=1;
                foreach($mobil as $mb) : ?>
                    <td><?php echo $no++ ?></td>
                    td><?php echo $mb->jenis ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mb->ukuran ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $mb->kapasitas ?></td>
```